# Time dilation from inside gravity well

Tags: general-relativity, visible-light, speed-of-light, time-dilation

If I were on the planet from interstellar where 1 hour = 7 years on earth and I had a super-powerful telescope and looked back at our galaxy, would I see the earth revolving around the sun at a super-fast speed?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, seven times an hour. You would need an x-ray telescope, because all the light from earth would also be oscillating at 61000 times the frequency.

Comment: I think the relationship between Doppler shift and time dilation for an orbiting object is more complicated than that.

Comment: @ProfRob why so? Its the exact same mechanism.

Comment: @FilipeMiguel Doppler shift depends (mainly) on velocity in the line of sight. For an object in orbit, this varies with time for any particular direction (except if the orbit is inclined face-on). Time dilation just depends on speed and position in the gravitational potential and wouldn't change.

Comment: @ProfRob I think @g s is talking exclusively about gravitational doppler shift. You could take the orbit of the planet to be in an orbit perpendicular to  the direction of earth. If we considered the general case, then the total doppler shift would be oscilating between some values that depend on the orbital velocity of the planet and I do not wish to estimate right now.

Comment: I don't think the orbital velocity of the planet is significant. From our perspective, the universe should look length contracted to the same factor that we are time dilated. Unless Earth measures our relative velocity to be very high in its own frame, Earth's velocity relative to us in our frame on Planet Black Hole contributes a trivial amount to the frequency shift of the light compared to the contribution of our time dilation. Certainly the difference in velocity relative to us between the earth and the sun is trivial.  (Deleted earlier comment, which was this but badly written.)